# App tabs usage with ion-tabs in Stencil + Ionic4 beta

Tags: ionic-framework, stenciljs, ionic4

I have used and examined Stencil.js and Ionic4 which is currently in beta version via [Ionic PWA Toolkit](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-pwa-toolkit). Ionic4 has no docs up to that moment since it has not been released yet.

When a tab item clicked, how to show its corresponding page which is possibly another component, ie. just the normal tab behavior?

I have tried a `root` attribute on an `ion-tab` but it throws `IonTabAttributes` does not contain `root`, so it is deprecated and changed I think.

`main.tsx` file's `render` function:

```
render() {
    return (
      <ion-app>
        <main>
          <ion-tabs>
            <ion-tab icon="home"></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab icon="document"></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab icon="pie"></ion-tab>
            <ion-tab icon="calendar"></ion-tab>
          </ion-tabs>
        </main>
      </ion-app>
    );
  }
```

I could use `stencil-router`, however, it seems a little bit anti-pattern when using `ion-tabs.

There are a few introductory video tutorials rather than written articles how to use it, but they are very basic and do not cover tabs usage.

Answer (score 0):

Put the content within each ion-tab. The content can be text or a component.

Answer (score 0):

`Ionic` will now use `angular router`. it will make use of angular router-outlets. for the tabbed application markup, each tab will be provided with a `named router outlet`.

Tabs are not a router-outlet on their own, that means each tab needs to contain its own sub-outlet to implement navigation. Routes will be defined like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      { // tab one
        path: 'schedule',
        component: SchedulePage,
        outlet: 'schedule'
      },
      { // tab two
        path: 'speakers',
        component: SpeakerListPage,
        outlet: 'speakers'
      },
      { // tab three
        path: 'map',
        component: MapPage,
        outlet: 'map'
      }
   ]
  }
];
```

Markup:

```
<ion-tabs>

    <ion-tab tabTitle="Schedule" href="/app/tabs/(schedule:schedule)">
      <ion-router-outlet name="schedule"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab tabTitle="Speakers" href="/app/tabs/(speakers:speakers)">
      <ion-router-outlet name="speakers"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab tabTitle="Map" href="/app/tabs/(map:map)">
      <ion-router-outlet name="map"></ion-router-outlet>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: can you help me here please.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341660/navigate-from-login-page-to-tabs-in-ionic4