# Navigate from Login page to Tabs in Ionic4?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4, router-outlet

I am creating an application and i want move from login Page to Tabs Page. When I try to navigate to Tabs page, its only showing Home page without Tabs.

here is my Code.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },

      { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**tabs.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { TabsPageRoutingModule } from './tabs.router.module';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { HomePageModule } from '../home/home.module';
import { ActivityPageModule } from '../activity/activity.module';
import { MygroupsPageModule } from '../mygroups/mygroups.module';
import { MessagesPageModule } from '../messages/messages.module';
import { SettingsPageModule } from '../settings/settings.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    TabsPageRoutingModule,
    HomePageModule, 
    ActivityPageModule,
    MygroupsPageModule,
    MessagesPageModule,
    SettingsPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [TabsPage]
})
export class TabsPageModule {}
```

**tabs.router.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home.page';
import { ActivityPage } from '../activity/activity.page';
import { MygroupsPage } from '../mygroups/mygroups.page';
import { MessagesPage } from '../messages/messages.page';
import { SettingsPage } from '../settings/settings.page';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        outlet: 'home',
        component: HomePage
      },
      {
        path: 'activity',
        outlet: 'activity',
        component: ActivityPage
      },
      {
        path: 'mygroups',
        outlet: 'mygroups',
        component: MygroupsPage
      },
      {
        path: 'messages',
        outlet: 'messages',
        component: MessagesPage
      },
      {
        path: 'settings',
        outlet: 'settings',
        component: SettingsPage
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

From Login page, I am navigating in this way.

```
this.router.navigate(['tabs']);
```

but this is  just showing a home page with no tabs. Can you guide me what should i do, even tabs are not showing in DOM, i tried to inspect them.
It is just showing Home Page as default Page.

Comment: is this  ionic project?

Comment: @AmiLinn yes in Ionic4's project

Comment: i'm not sure, i think this is not the correct way to do an ionic project.

Comment: @AmiLinn in Ionic4 , Tabs implementation is like this. I am following Ionic Template

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the navigation doen't work in tabs' page. To avoid the issue I did this :

```
this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home'); // I use NavCtroller instead of Router
```

and in app-routing.module.ts :

```
{ path: 'home', redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)' },
```

I hope it will work properly in the next beta.

Comment: But navCtrl is going to depreciate in ionic4 right?